# HttpSendRequest blocking when more than two downloads are already in progress

Tags: c++, http, wininet

In our program, a new thread is created each time an HTTP request needs to be made, and there can be several running simultaneously.  The problem I am having is that if I've got two threads already running, where they are looping on reading from `InternetReadFile()` after having called `HttpSendRequest()`, any subsequent attempts to call `HttpSendRequest()` just hang on that call, so I end up with the previously mentioned two threads continuing to read from their connections just fine, but the third just blocks on `HttpSendRequest()` until it times out.

From what I've been able to find on my own, this seems like it could just be the way wininet works, as [the HTTP spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) recommends: "A single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy."

I've seen various programs handle multiple simultaneous downloads to the same server, but I'd imagine they need to do a lot of extra work to do that, in terms of managing the various connections, or writing their own http interface.

If it would require a lot of extra complexity to set it up to handle more than two active sessions, then I would just change things to only handle one or two files at a time, leaving the rest queued.  However, if there were some low-complexity way to allow more than two at a time (off the top of my head, I'd guess using a new process per download might work, but would be messier), that would be preferable; it's not like it would be downloading more than 3-5 simultaneously anyway, and each download is at the user's request.  I read some mentions of registry hacks to change the limit, but that's definitely not something I'd do.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP 1.1 standard mandates a maximum of 2 simultaneous connections per server.  If you have IE5, IE6, or IE7 installed, the versions of WinInet they install allow you to use InternetSetOption() to increase the limit (look at INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_SERVER and INTERNET_OPTION_MAX_CONNS_PER_1_0_SERVER options).  However, the version of WinInet that is installed by with IE8 apparently disables that functionality (see http://connect.microsoft.com/WNDP/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=434396 and http://connect.microsoft.com/WNDP/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=481485).

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a lot more info, even if I might not be able to use that particular solution due to the changes in IE8.  I don't know why I wasn't able to find any of that in my searching, but I guess I wasn't looking in the right place.

Comment: Actually, after testing this, though I have IE8 installed, I can set the max connections to more than two, and it works (InternetQueryOption returns the value I set it to, and I actually am able to have the specified number of simultaneous connections).  Perhaps it's been changed again in a recent update, but I haven't found any confirmations of that.  And I figure, if someone has IE8, then they probably already update regularly, so if it has been fixed, then I should be set.

Answer (score -1):

If you call `InternetOpen()` multiple times, you should be able to simultaneously download two files on each `HINTERNET` returned by `InternetOpen()`.

Comment: I have tried both reusing the HINTERNET handle opened from InternetOpen(), and opening a new one per connection, but either way, it still limits the number of active connections to two, and I am trying to figure out of there's a way to increase that limit.

Comment: Yes, calling InternetOpen multiple times does not increase the number of simultaneous connections.