# Is MFC wininet CHttpConnection threadsafe?

Tags: multithreading, mfc, wininet

What happens if several threads open requests on the same CHttpConnection object at the same time? Are the requests queued or are they pipelined, or does it crash or malfunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the used WinINet handles have no thread affinity. So you can use such handles across threads.

Also I know that in older WinINet Version there was a limitation of 2 simultaneous requests per server. But this was released since the version shipped with IE8. You find information about this [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683540/httpsendrequest-blocking-when-more-than-two-downloads-are-already-in-progress).

I have bookmarked [this information about multithreading in WinINet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.wininet/jPiCBgrUEqE) a long time ago. It may help. But I didn't found more actual information about this.

So as far as I can see, it is safe to use multiple request on the same connection. And they should work parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The link to SO concerns several simultaneous connections to the same server, though, and is not relevant. I have only one connection but try to open several requests at once from different threads. The second link is useful and provides the answer, I guess. Your conclusion is valid.